# Angularjs how to make ngRoute without hash-bang

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

In my angularjs application I am having index.html in public folder which have below code,

```
<body ng-controller="TheController">
    <div id="startdiv">
        <label>Username</label><input type="text" tabindex="1" placeholder="Enter Your User Name" name="email" required>
        <label>Password</label><input type="password" tabindex="2"  placeholder="Enter Your Password" name="password" required>
        <br><br>
        <button ng-click="saveData()">Login</button><button ng-click="saveData()">SignUp</button><br>   
        <button ng-click="changeview()">ClickMe</button>
    </div>  
</body>
```

And the script part is as below,

```
var app = angular.module('plunker',['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
}]);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/test", {
        templateUrl : "index.html"
    })
    .when("/london", {
        templateUrl : "london.html",        
    });/*
    .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/paris.html'
        }); */
});


app.controller('TheController', function ($scope,$location) {       
    console.log('hello')    
     $scope.changeview = function () {
        console.log('in functgion changeview')
        console.log($location)
        $location.path('/london');      
    }
});
```

Also i have london.html in same public folder that i want to load on button click.

my london.html

```
<h1>London</h1>
<h3>London is the capital city of England.</h3>
```

The problem is , on button click the url is being changed from "http://localhost:3000/" to "http://localhost:3000/#/london" but html page is not loading. Also I want to know if it possible to route with hash character.

Please let me know where i am making mistake.
Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in `app.module.js`

> $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

**Example:**

```
window.routes = {
  '/': {
    templateUrl: 'app/visitor/visitor.html',
    anonymous: true
  },
  '/index': {
    templateUrl: 'app/visitor/visitor.html',
    caseInsensitiveMatch: true,
    anonymous: true
  },
  '/lu/:mt?/:tab?/:id?': {
    templateUrl: 'app/user/user.html',
    caseInsensitiveMatch: true,
    anonymous: false
  }
};

app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  for (var path in window.routes) {
    $routeProvider.when(path, window.routes[path]);
  }
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

Also as `templateUrl: 'app/visitor/visitor.html',` in sample, set full path to your files.